# Search string by regex in files and write line of found string

Tags: python, regex, file

I am searching in files with extensions .xml, .java, and .properties strings that match a certain regular expression.

When I find it, I write it to the file with the filename, line and string information.

```
def search(param):
    filename = "search-result.txt"
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except OSError:
        pass
    os.path.walk(param, step, None)

def step(ext, dirname, names):
    output = open("search-result.txt", "a")
    for name in names:
        if name.lower().endswith(".xml") or name.lower().endswith(".properties") or name.lower().endswith(".java"):
            path = os.path.join(dirname, name)
            filters = ["\\bin\\", "\\build\\", "logback", "\\test\\", "\\target\\"]
            if all(not filter in path for filter in filters):
                with open(path, "r") as lines:
                    print "Read: {}".format(path)
                    i = 1
                    for line in lines:
                        m = re.search(r"(!|$|RUP)\{[^:]*:[^\}]*\}", line)
                        if m is not None:
                            output.write("Path: {0}; \n    Line number: {1}; \n        {2}\n".format(path, i, line))
                        i += 1
    output.close()
```

I divided it into two functions - `search`, where I can check where result file is existed and remove it, and then `step` for `os.path.walk`. `Param` is a folder to search in.

How can this code be adjusted to look better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameter names are confusing: `param` and `ext`.

The `step()` function suffers from excessive nesting.  I would further subdivide your `step()` function to create a `search_path()` function that deals with each candidate file.  Since both of these helper functions aren't really that useful on their own, I would define them both within the main `search()` function.

You've hard-coded `"search-result.txt"` twice.  Ideally, it should be parameterized rather than hard-coded at all.  Furthermore, you're reopening it for appending each time you enter a directory, which is problematic because…

- Reopening the file handle is wasteful.
- You might not even have any search results for that directory.
- If you opened it just once in `'w'` mode instead of many times in `'a'` mode, you wouldn't have to remove the file at all. (Note that removing the file does make a difference, if the file exists and has a second hard-link.)

Also, `if all(not filter in path for filter in filters)` is inefficient.  As explained in the documentation for [`os.path.walk()`], you can avoid entering directories in which you have no interest:

> The *visit* function may modify names to influence the set of directories visited below *dirname*, e.g. to avoid visiting certain parts of the tree. (The object referred to by *names* must be modified in place, using [`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#del) or slice assignment.)

To analyze file extensions, use [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext).

Idiomatic Python loops rarely need statements like `i += 1`.  What you want to use is [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

The format string for `output.write()` is easier to read if spread out into several lines.

```
import os.path
import re

EXCLUDE_DIRS = ['bin', 'build', 'logback', 'test', 'target']

def search(directory, output_filename='search-result.txt'):
    def search_path(output, path):
        """Output search results for one file"""
        with open(path) as lines:
            print "Read: {}".format(path)
            for i, line in enumerate(lines, 1):
                if re.search(r"(!|$|RUP)\{[^:]*:[^\}]*\}", line):
                    output.write("Path: {0}; \n"
                                 "    Line number: {1}; \n"
                                 "        {2}\n".format(path, i, line))

    def step(output, dirname, names):
        """Filesystem traversal excluding certain directory names,
           calling search_path() for candidate files"""
        names[:] = [entry for entry in names if entry not in EXCLUDE_DIRS]
        for name in names:
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
            if ext.lower() in ('.xml', '.properties', '.java'):
                search_path(output, os.path.join(dirname, name))

    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output:
        os.path.walk(directory, step, output)
```